# C wire for smart thermostat

Tags: thermostat

I’m trying to add a smart thermostat and it seems I can’t find a C wire. I need to know where to tap in if I need to. It looks like I have extra wires on my thermostat wire going into the house.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: Updated wiring diagram][image: better picture of thermostat][image: better picture of wiring]

Comment: A higher resolution pic of the wiring diagram would be useful.

Comment: A higher resolution picture of the wiring  diagram will be an absolute necessity to be able to provide any guidance at all for this question.

Comment: the answer is in the second picture somewhere, but the details are all blurry.

Comment: Updated the wiring diagram

Comment: @Mattherr -- can you get us a close-up of the thermostat wiring?

Comment: Updated pictures

Answer (score 1):

### Move the yellow wire from your thermostat to where the blue wire is connected now...

Since whoever wired this up didn't use standard color codes, we'll have to go in and clean up a bit after their work first.  The first step is to remove the blue wire in the thermostat cable from its current junction with the yellow wire from your HVAC system.  Said yellow wire then gets nutted to the currently-unused yellow wire from your thermostat-cable, making that yellow wire the Y wire going up to the thermostat.

### ...and connect the blue wire from your thermostat to the grey wire from the HVAC system

Now that we have that taken care of, according to the wiring diagrams you posted, the grey wire from the transformer is your C wire.  In your photos, we can trace that grey wire over to one side of the compressor contactor, then from there down on to where it hangs behind the thermostat cable.  As a result, you can connect that grey wire to the now-free blue wire in your thermostat cable, wire up your new thermostat as normal, turn the HVAC back on, and enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for your help I will try this tomorrow

Comment: @Mattherr if this resolved your issue, please give the answer a check mark so others know that this has worked. Otherwise, consider updating your original question with some more information.